# Filter result of Custom Post Type using meta_query with ACF

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields, meta-query

Im using a custom post type named `property` to list some houses and flats. In this cpt, I have multiple custom fields from Advanced Custom Fields plugin, such as `localization`, `price`, `rooms` and so on. This is the HTML form I'm using to filter the results using `GET` method

```
<form>
  <button type="submit">filter</button>
  
  <select name="orderby" id="">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Order by:</option>
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="ASC">Lower price</option>
    <option value="DESC">Higher price</option>
  </select>

  <h3>Type of contract</h3>
  <select name="contract">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Select an option</option>
    <option value="rent">Rent</option>
    <option value="for_sale">For sale</option>
  </select>
  ...
</form>
```

In my loop I have this array, based on Codex. I'm using an example of nested arrays, did not work.

```
<?php 
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'property',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'price',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => $_GET['orderby'],
    'meta_query' => array(
       'relation' => 'AND',
           array(
              array(
                 'key'   => 'contract',
                 'value' => $_GET['contract'],
                 'compare' => '='
              ),
          array(
                 'key'   => 'rooms',
                 'value' => $_GET['rooms'],
                 'compare' => '='
          ),
          ...
          $query = new WP_Query($args);
             if($query->have_posts()) : while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post()
          ...
```

So for the listing of cpt based on this form as a filter using GET parameters, also ordering price by ASC or DESC, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

For meta_query with ACF and ordering price by ASC or DESC try following code.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'property',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'meta_key' => 'price',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
  'order' => $_GET['orderby'],
  'meta_query' => array(
      'relation' => 'AND',
      array(
        'key'   => 'contract',
        'value' => $_GET['contract'],
      ),
      array(
        'key'   => 'rooms',
        'value' => $_GET['rooms'],
      ),
      ...
   ),
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if($query->have_posts()) : 
   while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
      // your code 
   endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: Didnt work, even with only one parameter set in the filter. The loop didint find posts matching this query. Nested arrays are not required in this case?

Comment: You can add conditional agrs for wp_query like following code :
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'property',
  'posts_per_page' => -1
);
$args['meta_query'] = array('relation' => 'AND');
if( isset( $_GET['contract'] ) && ! empty( $_GET['contract'] ) ) {
    $args['meta_query'][] = array(
      'key'   => 'contract',
      'value' => $_GET['contract'],
    );
}
if( isset( $_GET['rooms'] ) && ! empty( $_GET['rooms'] ) ) {
    $args['meta_query'][] = array(
      'key'   => 'rooms',
      'value' => $_GET['rooms'],
    );
}